# R the best way to process data by column with a custom function

Tags: r, function, data.table

```
library(data.table)

df <- structure(list(
continuousNumericOne = c(3.82495116149284, 0.915662542284416, 0.751001771620762, NA, NA, 8.07583989184169, 4.57303752008246, 4.02747047825306, 2.79953011697721, 4.28614794390785), 
catagoricalFactorOne = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor"), 
continuousNumericTwo = c(NA, NA, 2.58285715825289, -2.71316582700148, 3.95645652249594, 1.96862094118233, 4.96960533647993, 6.15199683070215, 3.98091405116921, NA), 
catagoricalFactorTwo = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("blue", "orange", "red"), class = "factor"), 
continuousNumericThree = c(3.43332616062442, 2.21448227693603, 2.31889349781533, NA, NA, 3.57539465909581, 3.28076535012702, NA, 3.15063300766727, 2.9556632429251), 
continuousNumericFour = c(7.77131807052585, NA, 6.5830522592014, NA, 7.36003333388333, 8.25217350122047, 7.18282902739316, 8.60641407074177, 4.87689328481095, NA)), 
.Names = c("continuousNumericOne", "catagoricalFactorOne", "continuousFactorTwo", "catagoricalFactorTwo", "continuousNumericThree", "continuousNumericFour"), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

> df
    continuousNumericOne catagoricalFactorOne continuousFactorTwo catagoricalFactorTwo continuousNumericThree continuousNumericFour
 1:            3.8249512                  red                  NA                  red               3.433326              7.771318
 2:            0.9156625                  red                  NA                  red               2.214482                    NA
 3:            0.7510018                  red            2.582857                  red               2.318893              6.583052
 4:                   NA                   NA           -2.713166                   NA                     NA                    NA
 5:                   NA                  red            3.956457                  red                     NA              7.360033
 6:            8.0758399                   NA            1.968621                  red               3.575395              8.252174
 7:            4.5730375                green            4.969605               orange               3.280765              7.182829
 8:            4.0274705                green            6.151997               orange                     NA              8.606414
 9:            2.7995301                green            3.980914               orange               3.150633              4.876893
10:            4.2861479                   NA                  NA                 blue               2.955663                    NA
```

How could one make a custom function to process the data as follows...

1. If the column is a categorical (factor), replace all NAs with 'blank'
2. If the column is continuous (numerical), additional flexibility to further process the data, for example, to first scale the data 0 to 1, and then replace the NA's if desired, maybe with -1.1.

I have spent considerable time making lists, 
attempting to keep track of column names and whether a given column name is factor or not, 
trying different functions applied via apply methods, still with no luck.

If there is a better approach, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a function

```
f1 <- function(dat){
 iCat <- which(sapply(dat, is.factor))
 iNum <- which(sapply(dat, is.numeric))
 dat[, (iCat) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
              levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "")
              x[is.na(x)] <- ""
              x}), .SDcols = iCat]  
  dat[, (iNum) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
                 x1 <- as.vector(scale(x))
                 x1[is.na(x1)] <- -1.1
                 x1}), .SDcols = iNum][]
 }

f1(df)
#continuousNumericOne catagoricalFactorOne continuousFactorTwo
# 1:           0.07257304                  red          -1.1000000
# 2:          -1.18235090                  red          -1.1000000
# 3:          -1.25337745                  red          -0.1400258
# 4:          -1.10000000                               -1.9826003
# 5:          -1.10000000                  red           0.3378723
# 6:           1.90619723                               -0.3537288
# 7:           0.39526068                green           0.6903636
# 8:           0.15992990                green           1.1017373
# 9:          -0.36974314                green           0.3463815
#10:           0.27151063                               -1.1000000
#    catagoricalFactorTwo continuousNumericThree continuousNumericFour
# 1:                  red             0.83246346            0.43436598
# 2:                  red            -1.45562130           -1.10000000
# 3:                  red            -1.25961447           -0.52487557
# 4:                                 -1.10000000           -1.10000000
# 5:                  red            -1.10000000            0.10235154
# 6:                  red             1.09916272            0.82254218
# 7:               orange             0.54606741           -0.04069872
# 8:               orange            -1.10000000            1.10850704
# 9:               orange             0.30177540           -1.90219245
#10:                 blue            -0.06423321           -1.10000000
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your example data has names with `"Factor"` for numeric columns. So I'm providing my own example data.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.table(
  num1 = runif(10),
  fac1 = factor(sample(letters, 10)),
  num2 = runif(10),
  fac2 = factor(sample(letters, 10)),
  char = sample(letters, 10)
)
```

As for the task, method dispatch with a generic function fits the bill.

```
process.factor <- function(x) {
  # Replace with actual logic
  rep_len("f", length(x))
}

process.numeric <- function(x) {
  # Replace with actual logic
  rep_len("n", length(x))
}

process.default <- function(x) {
  # Replace with actual logic for "other" classes not specifically handled
  rep_len("d", length(x))
}

process <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("process")
}
```

Then we just `lapply` the columns inside the `data.table`, which results in another `data.table`.

```
df[, lapply(.SD, process)]
#     num1 fac1 num2 fac2 char
#  1:    n    f    n    f    d
#  2:    n    f    n    f    d
#  3:    n    f    n    f    d
#  4:    n    f    n    f    d
#  5:    n    f    n    f    d
#  6:    n    f    n    f    d
#  7:    n    f    n    f    d
#  8:    n    f    n    f    d
#  9:    n    f    n    f    d
# 10:    n    f    n    f    d
```

Comment: What if there are other columns that aren't factors or numeric? `process.default <- function(x) x`?

Comment: `process.default` would be a catch-all for objects you didn't make a `process.foo` for.  You can make `process.character`, `process.raw`, whatever you need.  And `process` can stay as just a call to `UseMethod`. Edit - added `process.default` to answer, because it is the right thing to do.

Comment: So you may have to replace with `process.factor <- function(x) {
    levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "");
    x[is.na(x)] <- "";
    x
}` and `process.numeric <- function(x) {
     x <- as.vector(scale(x));
     x[is.na(x)] <- -1.1;
     x
}`

Comment: Correct.  I didn't include the processing steps you gave because they didn't seem necessary for the question.  I just wanted to show a way *how* to go about it, *what* people do depends on the task at hand.